# Building a DateTime with a specific timezone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I have a date, an hour, and a timezone. From these, I'm trying to build a UTC DateTime.

Everything I've googled about building a DateTime with a timezone is talking about going *to* a different timezone from UTC, not the other way around. `DateTime` seems to only take ints for time/date values, and nothing for a timezone.

This seems like such a simple problem but for some reason the solution is eluding me.

How do I build a DateTime with date, hour, and timezone?

Comment: If you downvote, please explain why. I understand this is a pretty simple question, but my efforts to search didn't yield anything useful -- as I addressed in my second paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
datetime = '2015-05-25 12:00 +0300'
Time.parse(datetime).utc
```

First you parse time with timezone (default = current timezone) and then convert it to UTC. Same can be done with `DateTime`